# Nginx to Apache HTTPS routing

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

I have a Nginx software on ubuntu configured as a reverse proxy for all traffic to the internal upstream server. 
Also, on the same nginx server, I have an Apache Server to serve sites.

I am trying to route traffic from Nginx (443) to Apache (8443) and it is not working. SSL certificates are configured on both Nginx and Apache, tried to configure one or other, both it didn't work.

Error seen in the browser:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

Comment: What is your Nginx proxy configuration?

Comment: Please show us the `proxy_pass` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

i csnt yet comment, sry but i bet you tried to access plesk via 8443 over nginx via http://dom:8443 instead https://dom:8443